# In PowerShell $Profile, test for Morning, Afternoon, or evening and make the selection a certain font color, like "Good morning Ken" in blue font

Tags: powershell

I have an if statement in my $profile file that will test the time of day and output a greeting such as "Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", etc. I just want the fone color to be, oh I don't know, let say purple.

```
If ($Hour -lt 12) {"Good Morning Ken!"}  

ElseIf ($Hour -gt 17) {"Good Eventing Ken!"}
  
Else {"Good Afternoon Ken!"}
```

The resulting command prompt that I get whenever I open PowerShell is:

Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\Ken\PowerShellTranscript\MyTranscript.txt
**Good Afternoon Ken!**  **<-- I'd like this to have a different color when it Writes to my console.**
Today is Saturday, November 5, 2022
PowerShell Version: 5
Computer Name = HPLAPTOP
Happy scripting!

PS C:>

Obviously, I don't know what I'm doing here, so I tried several things with (), {}, and piping to Write-Host
But nothing gets me a changed font color.

I tried using Write-Host, with and without various things such as:

```
If ($Hour -lt 12) {"Good Morning Ken!"} | Write-Host -ForgroundColor Magenta

ElseIf ($Hour -gt 17) {"Good Eventing Ken!"} | Write-Host -ForgroundColor Magenta
  
Else {"Good Afternoon Ken!"} | Write-Host -ForgroundColor Magenta
```

Comment: You're trying to pipe after a language keyword (`if`) that's not possible. Your `Write-Host` statements should be inside the `if` conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving the typo (`-ForgroundColor` instead of `-ForegroundColor`) aside, you just need to move the `}` on each line to the *end* of that line, so that each `"Good ..."` string is directly piped to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host):

```
If ($Hour -lt 12) {"Good Morning, Ken!" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta }
ElseIf ($Hour -gt 17) {"Good Eventing, Ken!" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta }
Else {"Good Afternoon, Ken!" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta }
```

However, you can streamline your approach:

```
('Good {0}, Ken' -f $(
  If ($Hour -lt 12) { 'Morning' }
  ElseIf ($Hour -gt 17) { 'Evening' }
  Else { 'Afternoon' }
)) | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

Note the need to enclose the [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statement in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), so that it can participate in the expression that uses `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).

Comment: @okskinner :) I'm glad we got there; my pleasure.